# Datastax 5.0 AMI on AWS installation fails

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup

We are trying to set up Datastax Enterprise cluster on AWS. We want to use the community Datastax AMI that is provided by https://github.com/riptano/ComboAMI/

Before Datastax Enterprise 5.0 edition, we were installing 4.8, entire process was running OK.

Today, when we wanted to install cluster following usual procedure explained [here](http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/5.0/datastax_enterprise/install/installAMI.html) , we get following error in 
`~/datastax_ami/ami.log` trace:

`[INFO] Checking for 15 seconds to ensure Cassandra stays up...
[EXEC] 06/30/16-10:47:38 nodetool info:
DSE 5.0 requires Java 8u40 or later.
[EXEC] 06/30/16-10:47:39 nodetool info:
DSE 5.0 requires Java 8u40 or later.
[EXEC] 06/30/16-10:47:40 nodetool info:
DSE 5.0 requires Java 8u40 or later.
[EXEC] 06/30/16-10:47:42 nodetool info:
DSE 5.0 requires Java 8u40 or later.
[ERROR] 06/30/16-10:47:43 sudo service datastax-agent restart:
datastax-agent: unrecognized service`

It seems that DSE 5.0 requires java 1.8, while java 1.7 is being installed, which I confirmed by executing on one of the machines in the cluster:
`java -version`

Result was

`java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)`

Also, when we tried installing previous versions of DSE on AWS using AMI, we were also getting errors.

Why there is no Java 1.8 available in AMI distribution?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataStax AMI Repo is strictly on maintenance mode and is going to be phased out in December.

> This project is currently in a maintenance mode until December 2016. During this timeframe, DataStax will no longer provide updates for DataStax ComboAMI. Beyond this timeframe, we will stop hosting the central service and delete this repository. Users who wish to use this service are encouraged to fork this project and host the reflector service themselves. If you are using a paid version of DataStax Enterprise, you can leverage OpsCenter 6.0 Lifecycle Manager to provision clusters.

https://github.com/riptano/ComboAMI/commit/d1bf356b39b93f09fc10967a57b71152626c54a1

The replacement is Lifecycle Manager that was released with OpsCenter 6.0. Lifecycle Manager can take a machine with a supported OS and fully install/configure DSE based off the specified configuration profiles.

I highly recommend starting a machine, installing OpsCenter 6.0 and then using LCM to install/configure the rest of your nodes.

http://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/6.0/opsc/install/opscInstallDeb_t.html

http://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/6.0/opsc/LCM/opscLCM.html